# Make the first row fixed while scrolling or sorting in NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

I have a NSTableView in I want the the first row to be fixed.
I do not want the first row to be sorted while clicking on the header of any table column. The row  should also be fixed while scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two ways to go:
Add a proprety to the objects in the tableview. For instance a boolean named 'isFirstRow'. Set this object to YES for the row you want first and add a sortDescriptor based on this property.
(I think this is the most clean solution).

Or remove the row from the tableArray, build the table and add this row back on the first position.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get either of your solutions.As in first case : The table is bind to an arraycontroller and in that values are populated from a list. Where do i suppose to add the boolean property(as suggested by you). And in 2nd case: how can i add the row back at 1st position. Please clarify.

Comment: In the first case: what kind of objects does your arrayController contain? NSDictionaries? In that case add a key-value pair to the dictionary. For the second case: your arraycontroller is bound to a mutableArray I suppose? In this array you can use for example `[myMutableArray removeObjectAtIndex:x]` and after sorting/filling the arraycontroller you can use `[myMutableArray addObjectAtIndex:0]`

Comment: I am still not able to get the required functionality. I am using ISTCF framework. My array controller is bind to a ISTEntityList. And I am adding ISTEntity to it.

Comment: I am adding ISTEntity to add separate entities to the list. After populating the arraycontroller i added the entity , which i want as the first row. [[self myEntityList] prependEntity:newEntity];  The prepended row is coming at 1st row, but while scrolling the table view it gets scrolled along with other rows.

Comment: Oops, sorry. I think I didn't fully understand your first request. The methods I described were to place one row at the top, but not staying at top when scrolling. I wonder whether this is possible. Maybe it's better (and clearer for the user) to make a separate interface-element for this top row?

Comment: I tried adding a separate table header only for that row but that doesn't seem to work either. In this i am getting a problem regarding,synchronizing  horizontal scrolling for both table view.

Comment: Didn't try myself, but isn't it possible to bind each corresponding columnWidth of both tableViews?

Comment: Maybe catch scrolling and scroll the other table the same by code. This is my code to track scrolling in a webView. The tableView also has a ScrollView. `NSClipView *descriptionWebClipView = [[descriptionWebView enclosingScrollView] contentView];
    [descriptionWebClipView setPostsBoundsChangedNotifications:YES];
    
    NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] ;
    [center addObserver: self
               selector: @selector(boundsDidChangeNotification:)
                   name: NSViewBoundsDidChangeNotification
                 object: descriptionWebClipView];`